# Query table and column comments in HIVE Metastore

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2, hive-metastore

I am trying to figure out how to query table and column comments (descriptions) in HIVE Metastore. If there is a way to add the comments to HIVE tables/columns, shouldn't be a way to query/report on the comments from HIVE Metastore?

Please help :)

Best Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DBS.NAME AS OWNER,
        TBLS.TBL_NAME as OBJECT_NAME,
        TBL_COMMENTS.TBL_COMMENT as OBJECT_DESCRIPTION,
        TBLS.TBL_ID as OBJECT_ID,
        TBLS.TBL_TYPE as OBJECT_TYPE,
        'VALID' as OBJECT_STATUS,
        COLUMNS_V2.COLUMN_NAME,
        COLUMNS_V2.COMMENT as COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
        COLUMNS_V2.TYPE_NAME AS DATA_TYPE,
        'Y' as NULL_IND,
        'N' as PRIMARY_KEY_IND,
        TBLS.CREATE_TIME as LAST_DDL_TIME
FROM    DBS
        JOIN TBLS 
                ON DBS.DB_ID = TBLS.DB_ID
        JOIN SDS 
                ON TBLS.SD_ID = SDS.SD_ID
        JOIN COLUMNS_V2 
                ON COLUMNS_V2.CD_ID = SDS.CD_ID
        JOIN (SELECT    DISTINCT 
                        TBL_ID, 
                        TBL_COMMENT 
              FROM     (SELECT  TBLS.TBL_ID TBL_ID, 
                                TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_KEY, 
                                TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE, 
                                CASE WHEN TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_KEY = 'comment' 
                                        THEN TABLE_PARAMS.PARAM_VALUE 
                                                ELSE '' 
                                END TBL_COMMENT
                        FROM    TBLS 
                                JOIN TABLE_PARAMS
                                        ON TBLS.TBL_ID = TABLE_PARAMS.TBL_ID) TBL_COMMENTS_INTERNAL) TBL_COMMENTS 
                ON TBLS.TBL_ID = TBL_COMMENTS.TBL_ID;
```